# Rotating $3D$ one point to the other point

Tags: 3d, robotics

Let's say I have a point $A \ (1,2,3)$ and point $B\ (2,3,4)$
If I want to get point $B$ from point $A$ using angles between $A$ and $B$ in $x,y,z$ axis. How can I get point $B$ from point $A$?
Here is my method:
Get a direction vector from $A$ and $B$ then I can have three degrees in the $x,y,z$-axis. Calculate the degree between $A$ and $B$ and apply rotation matrices for each axis.
However, I am not getting the same point as $B$ if I did like that.
How can I get the point $B$ from point $A$ using angles?

Comment: Since $A,B$ and the origin are coplanar, you can form a rotation matrix in that plane, then up to a pair of rotation matrices to transform some viewing angle to the plane of $A,B$ with the origin.  Note that applying non-symmetric rotations in differing orders may produce different results.

Comment: Note that $A$ and $B$ are at different distances, so a rotation around an axis through origin will not be sufficient. You will need a scaling as well

Comment: You need to add translation to your transfoirmation.

Comment: Those points A and B are just random example. Before the scaling, I should get a same direction cosines but I am not getting it even if I used rotation matrices..